# TIBCO Spotfire logs export

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I want to export log of steps I have done transforming and comparing 2 files in Spotfire 3.2.1 
I went through all the possible options on the ribbon and file help, and I am not able to find it.
Would anybody know how to obtain txt logs in Spotfire, please?

Comment: You want to capture every click, calculation, expression entered, etc? Or just what the file import and transformation is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find these steps under **Edit>>Data Table Properties**, then click the **Source Information**. you'll see a dialog like the one below.

[image]

Comment: you're welcome! if the solution works, could you mark the answer as correct?

Comment: @user6618529 glad Niko helped you out. Be sure to accept his answer and vote on useful posts in the future.

Comment: I was afk for few days, sorry Guys! Marked now and thank you for your help!